# Which place api service giving more accurate data

Tags: web-services, google-maps-api-3, foursquare, here-api

I'm working windows phone app and going to use place api from web service and after doing some searching I get 3 web service : here place api, google place api, and foursquare api... so which one have the most accurate, informative data for user and location coverage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Accurate** and **Informative** are subjective terms. Informative in what way? Is it *breadth* of data you are after (i.e. most locations) or *depth* (most information about a place, more reviews, pictures etc.) or *freshness* (weeding out closed places, updating phone numbers etc.) Must the location be precise down to  eight decimal places or is four good enough? What use is excellent coverage in Europe say, if the market for my app is based in Indonesia? and so on.

In my opinion, your best option here would be to run a simple **beauty contest** as described in a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722847/adequate-places-api-for-travel-app) and base the results on the factors that are most important to **you**.

Comment: wow, thank you for giving a complete explanation, I think I will stick with here place api (nokia) since this is api that I use when I starting making my apps